# Como alterar o repositório remoto do Github?

Tags: github

Eu tenho um projeto finalizado e comitado no Github. Agora que quero fazer uma cópia da pasta para fazer alguns testes e quero enviar esse projeto para um novo repositorio no Github. O problema é que essa cópia esta sendo direcionada para o repositorio da primeira versão e eu não quero mexer na primeira versão, eu quero fazer os commits num novo repositorio.

Como faço pra desvincular o repositorio do antigo projeto nesse novo que foi cópia do projeto anteior?

Obs.: Eu já fiz muitas alterações no novo projeto e não quero perde-lás.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abra Terminal e vá ate a pasta do projeto.

Altere o diretório de trabalho atual referente ao seu projeto local.
Liste seus remotes existentes para obter o nome do remote que deseja alterar.

```
$ git remote -v
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Altere a URL do remote de SSH para HTTPS com o comando git remote set-url.

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Verifique se o URL remote foi alterado.

```
$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote URL
> origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Comment: blz. o nome do primeiro projeto é gymManager e a pasta copiada alterei o nome para gymBD.

quando eu acessei a pasta gymBD fiz o "$ git remote -v" apareceu o nome gymManager. eu preciso agora criar um novo repositorio gymBD no github e executar o "git remote set-url"?